# Mobile menu scrollbar on ios not visible

Tags: ios, css, scrollbar

I have a problem with the scrollbar in the drop down menu in iOS.

I would like it to stay always visible when I open the menu, but this only works on Android and not in iOS. This is the code I have used

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 2px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color:  #E2BC69;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

On CanIUse these properties are available on iOS (tested on iOS 9 and 10). Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you could try overflow:visible;
Some html code or even a fiddle can be helpful your question is not clear

Comment: Thanks to answer, but it does not work. This is an image of the problem http://imgur.com/a/oEw0J . The scrollbar works in both systems but in iOS is not seen.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem, the mobile menu style must be:

`.navbar-collapse {
     overflow-y: scroll;
     webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
     }`